# What is the main difference in Attachable and Detachable threads. Is it somthing related to CPU overhead

Tags: c, pthreads

```
pthread_t tid;
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thr_loop, NULL);
```

**What does happen if i pass some value apart from passing the NULL?**

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) the last argument is a user defined argument which is passed to the function that is called by the new thread.

```
 static void *
   thread_start(void *arg)
   {
       struct thread_info *tinfo = arg;
       char *uargv, *p;

       printf("Thread %d: top of stack near %p; argv_string=%s\n",
               tinfo->thread_num, &p, tinfo->argv_string);

       uargv = strdup(tinfo->argv_string);
       if (uargv == NULL)
           handle_error("strdup");

       for (p = uargv; *p != '\0'; p++)
           *p = toupper(*p);

       return uargv;
   }
```

And later they call the the `pthread_create` as follows

```
pthread_create(&tinfo[tnum].thread_id, &attr,&thread_start, &tinfo[tnum]);
```

As you can see there an argument passed to the function which is then passed
to the `thread_start` function. You can pass everything you like here.

#### Update:

I just saw, that you maybe ment some other `NULL` value as well. So let me explain this as well:

1. `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED` - If the calling thread don't want to wait for the termination of the created thread you should create it with this state.
2. `PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE` - It is assumed that you are waiting on the thread in some way, e.g. `pthread_join`

For further reading I can recommend [this](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node30.html) webpage.